# Particles JS is not covering full page

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

**Hello!**

My problem is with Particles JS, it doesn't cover my page. There is a space at the top.
[image]

**HTML:**

```
...
<body>
    ...
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
        <img alt="Server Name" draggable="false" id="Logo" src="assets/img/logo.png">
        <div id="Navigation">
            <a href="#"><img alt="Forums" draggable="false" src="assets/img/icon_exemple.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img alt="Store" draggable="false" src="assets/img/icon_exemple.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img alt="Vote" draggable="false" src="assets/img/icon_exemple.png"></a>
        </div>
        <button id="Server" onclick="copyToClipboard('server.ip:port')"><span>Join to us</span></button>
    ...
</body>
...
```

**CSS:**

```
...
body {
  background-image: url(../img/background.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
#particles-js {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -100;
}
...
```

I tried to solve the problem myself trying different options but nothing.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We don't what you tried. Have you removed the margin and padding from the `body, html` tags? Have you tried setting a `top` and `left` value for your `#particles-js` element?

Comment: What HTML is there between the body tag and the particles element (those .....) ? It looks as though it's getting fixed relative to something other than the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add position values to #particle-js

```
#particles-js {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -100;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

Comment: I changed the bottom value and it worked. Thanks!